# How can I create populate a <select> inside a directive template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created this Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/arDdiLzShLI9lKTTAKGW?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = {"id":1,"name":"One"},
                   {"id":2,"name":"Two"},
                   {"id":3,"name":"Three"};
  $scope.exam = 99;
  $scope.typeChanged = function() {
    alert($scope.exam)
  }
});

app.directive("adminSelect", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            adminChange: "&",
            adminModel: "=",
            options: "="
        },
        template: '<select ng-change="adminChange()" \
                          ng-model="adminModel" \
                          ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in options"></div>',
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        }
    };
});
```

Here's the HTML that calls the directive:

```
<div admin-select
  label="ExamType"
  admin-change="typeChanged()"
  admin-model="exam"
  options="options"></div>

  Type: {{ exam }}
```

Can someone tell me why my select box is not getting populated also how can I get the alert to give me the correct value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are trying to do something like this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/W1MMx7vjKKXFuV8LbBjJ?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = [{"id":1,"name":"One"},
                   {"id":2,"name":"Two"},
                   {"id":3,"name":"Three"}];
  $scope.typeChanged = function(){alert("it changed!");};
  $scope.exam = $scope.options[0];
});

app.directive("adminSelect", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            label: '=adminLabel',
            change: "&adminChange",
            innerModel: "=adminModel",
            options: "=adminOptions"
        },
        template: '<div><select ng-change="change()" \
                          ng-model="innerModel" \
                          ng-options="item.name for item in options"></div>'
    };
});
```

**UPDATE**

I have found a work around for your issue, you can do it like this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/VWaRWM4KhfU4VWVPSp2E?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = [{"id":1,"name":"One"},
                   {"id":2,"name":"Two"},
                   {"id":3,"name":"Three"}];
  $scope.typeChanged = function(item){alert(item.name);};
  $scope.exam = $scope.options[0];
});

app.directive("adminSelect", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            label: '=adminLabel',
            change: "&adminChange",
            innerModel: "=adminModel",
            options: "=adminOptions"
        },
        template: '<div><select ng-change="innerTypeChanged()" \
                          ng-model="innerModel" \
                          ng-options="item.name for item in options"></div>',
        controller: function($scope){
          $scope.innerTypeChanged = function(){
            $scope.change({item:$scope.innerModel});
          };
        }
    };
});
```

You will also need to update this line:

```
  admin-change="typeChanged(item)"
```

Comment: That's right but my problem is getting the correct value to show in the alert. Can you try the plunker that I created and you can see it doesn't give the correct number.

Comment: @Marilou oh, I see, give me 5 minutes, I'm in the middle of something else, I will update the answer as soon as I'm done. Have you checked my plunker BTW?

Comment: @Joseph - Yes I checked your plunkr thanks and it works but your version doesn't include the alerting of the value. Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: @Marilou you will be happy to know that I've found a workaround for your issue, please check my latest updated, thanks!

Comment: @Joesph - Thanks. I will look into this now and try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your $scope.options is not an Array.

You forgot to wrap it into an [].

```
$scope.options = [{"id":1,"name":"One"},
               {"id":2,"name":"Two"},
               {"id":3,"name":"Three"}];
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated the Plunker. Do you have any idea why the alert does not show the right value when I do a select ?